# How do I copy file data to NSMutable Dictionary on objective C.?

Tags: objective-c

i m struggling to get this thing done. 
I read the file and i have to put every record of file in nsmutable dictionary . Anyone having any idea???

Comment: Show us your code and where you're having a problem.

Comment: Your question is rather unanswerable right now. How is the file structured? Is it a plist file? A text file with delimited key-value pairs?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to retrieve information from a file?
In that case you could use property lists.
Just create a plist with Propertylisteditor.
Then load it with

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"path/to/file.plist"]
```